# Scheduled task to check for updates (0x1 error)

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, intune

I'm trying to create a scheduled task that basically checks for update for the application and if there is to install it.
Set to

- System account
- Run with highest privilege
- Run whether user is log on or not

It works fine when I log in on a administrator account
However when i ran it on a normal user account I got a 0x1 job status.

How should I go about implementing it?

Comment: Let the user running the scheduled task have admin permissions

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the user account read/write/change permissions to the
   `C:\Windows\System32\tasks`
2. Edit GPO Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration ->
   Windows Settings ->  Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Log on
   as a batch job